# Conteúdo de uma matriz receber o de outra

Tags: java

Matriz principal:

```java
    public static String [][] matrizPrincipal(){
        String [] [] matriz = new String [2] [6];
        matriz[0][0] = "Robin Arryn";
        matriz[0][1] = "Lino Facioli";
        matriz[0][2] = "145";
        matriz[0][3] = "Vivo";
        matriz[0][4] = "Arryn";
        matriz[0][5] = "Masculino";

        matriz[1][0] = "Yohn Royce";
        matriz[1][1] = "Rupert Vansittart";
        matriz[1][2] = "45";
        matriz[1][3] = "Vivo";
        matriz[1][4] = "Arryn";
        matriz[1][5] = "Masculino";
        return matriz;
    }
```

Estou tentando criar uma nova matriz que armazena apenas o conteúdo que esteja na coluna 0, ou seja, na posição `matriz[i][0]`

Porém não estou obtendo sucesso no novo método. Estou tentando criá-lo assim:

```java
public static String [] [] novaMatriz(String [] [] mat){
        String [] [] matriz2 = new String [mat.length] [1];
        for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++){
                matriz2[i][0] = mat[i][0];
        }
        return matriz2;
}
```

Qual seria o problema? como proceder?
Quando eu tento chamar este *return* resulta nisso:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@dc0772
```

Comment: `String [] [] matriz2 = new String [2] [2];`
não deveria ser
`String [] [] matriz2 = new String [mat.length] [2];`
?

Comment: Acho que o mais correto seria mesmo `[mat.length][1]`, pois só preciso de uma coluna para armazenar os nomes. Porém o problema persiste..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem dois problemas aqui.

Primeiro, que se a sua matriz no final terá apenas uma coluna, então ela não precisa ter duas dimensões, fica mais fácil de trabalhar usando apenas uma:

```
public static String[] pegaPrimeiraLinha(String[][] mat) {
    String[] matriz2 = new String[mat.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        matriz2[i] = mat[i][0];
    }
    return matriz2;
}
```

O segundo problema é que ao fazer isso:

```
String[] array = ...; // Ou pode ser com duas ou mais dimensões também que vai dar na mesma.
System.out.println(matriz);
```

Para que a matriz (ou qualquer outro objeto passado para o `System.out.println`) seja convertida para uma `String`, o método `toString()` deste será chamado. E é aqui que está o problema. ***Arrays* não implementam o método `toString()`!** Como resultado a implementação chamada será a da classe `Object`. A [implementação do `toString()` da classe `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) apenas devolve o nome da classe seguido de um arroba e do `hashCode` em hexadecimal, o que não é uma representação muito útil.

O que você tem que fazer então é usar um método que faça a conversão para `String` de uma forma que faça sentido. Na classe [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) há um método [`toString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-) que servirá ao seu propósito. Desta forma o seu programa ficará assim:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Matrizes {
    public static String[][] matrizPrincipal() {
        String[][] matriz = new String[2][6];
        matriz[0][0] = "Robin Arryn";
        matriz[0][1] = "Lino Facioli";
        matriz[0][2] = "145";
        matriz[0][3] = "Vivo";
        matriz[0][4] = "Arryn";
        matriz[0][5] = "Masculino";

        matriz[1][0] = "Yohn Royce";
        matriz[1][1] = "Rupert Vansittart";
        matriz[1][2] = "45";
        matriz[1][3] = "Vivo";
        matriz[1][4] = "Arryn";
        matriz[1][5] = "Masculino";
        return matriz;
    }

    public static String[] pegaPrimeiraLinha(String[][] mat) {
        String[] matriz2 = new String[mat.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            matriz2[i] = mat[i][0];
        }
        return matriz2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] matriz = matrizPrincipal();
        String[] reduzida = pegaPrimeiraLinha(matriz);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reduzida));
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no IdeOne.](http://ideone.com/IZmMPb)

Comment: O programa retornou o seguinte erro: http://puu.sh/hQpgX/1dbb696b40.png

Comment: Certifique-se que você tem a linha do import no começo do código:
`import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: @Guilherme Como o Otávio disse, verifique se você não esqueceu o `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: Era isso mesmo, funcionou! Muito obrigado