# Retornar o inverso de um vetor

Tags: java

Como faço para inverter os valore de um vetor?
Exemplo:

`1 2 3` virar `3 2 1`

Estou atualmente tentando fazer um método do tipo..

```
public static int [] vetorInvertido(int [] vet){
    int [] vetInvert = new int[vet.length];
        for(int i=vet.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            for(int j=0; j<=vetInvert.length; j++){
            vetInvert[j] = vet[i];
           }
        }
        return vetInvert;
    }
```

Comment: Duplicada do Stack em inglês, de uma olhada: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
public static int[] vetorInvertido(int[] vet) {
    int tamanho = vet.length;
    int[] vetInvert = new int[tamanho];
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        vetInvert[tamanho - 1 - i] = vet[i];
    }
    return vetInvert;
}
```

A razão é que no código que você fez tem um problema:

```
        vetInvert[i] = vet[i];
```

No seu código, ele vai apenas copiar o vetor, a ordem que você itera as posições não importa. O que você tem que fazer é colocar as posições de um como o inverso do outro, tal como no código do começo desta resposta:

```
        vetInvert[tamanho - 1 - i] = vet[i];
```

Comment: No seu código eu obtive um resultado estranho... `[I@13af427`

Comment: @Guilherme É por causa disso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64371/132 - Basicamente, o `System.out.println` não funciona normalmente com nenhum array, pois arrays não implementam o `toString()`. Você deve usar `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));` ao invés de `System.out.println(array);`.

Comment: valeu, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2):

Usando *Collections* do Java obter a ordem inversa é bem simples:

```
Integer vetor[] = {1,2,3};
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(vetor));
```

Com isso, a ordem dos elementos do vetor `vetor[]` será invertida.

Answer (score 0):

Se puder usar a biblioteca externa [commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) é necessario somente uma chamada a um método:

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(array);
```