# Preciso inverter um vetor

Tags: java

Preciso saber como mudo essa logica para receber vetores de qualquer tamanho.

```
public void inverter(int[] vetor) {
    int i;
    int temp;

    for(i=0; i < 3; i++){
    temp = vetor[i];
    vetor[i] = vetor[8-i];
    vetor[8-i] = temp;
    }


}
```

> Ex: int[] vetor1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
>
> //Imprime [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

Comment: Cara sou novo aqui e não entendo muito como funciona. O que devo fazer para conseguir essa ajuda que eu postei. Obrigado

Comment: Quando uma pergunta é marcada como duplicata, é porque ela já possui resposta. Voce acessou os links que indiquei na outra pergunta?

Comment: entra no Stackoverflow meta em portugues la tem todas as regras, normalmente no começo pessoal e bem rude mesmo , mais se acostuma

Comment: @MarceloBatista quem foi rude aqui? Se fecha sem falar nada reclamam, se fecha e da um toque no autor, é rude, está dificil demais agradar aqui.

Comment: nao falei de voce, em geral essa e a percepção com qualquer pergunta mais fraca digamos

Comment: Calma pessoal rsrs

Comment: Isso resolve o problema https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64830/3635 ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento até ajuda, mas eu preciso que seja um método void sem retorno.

Comment: @SnSilva da uma olhada https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: Valeu @MarceloBatista vou dar uma olhada.

Comment: Mas porque tem que ser `void` ou não? Afinal é só um método que você vai adicionar a sua classe para um uso especifico e unico, não vejo sentido ou necessidade para que isto seja void, afinal vc pode criar mais de um método, quantos quiser e cada um para uma necessidade ;)

Comment: É uma atividade que o professor passou no repl.it e o método que está lá é void e eu não posso alterar, somente tenho que fazer a logica dentro desse método @GuilhermeNascimento.

Comment: @SnSilva se não quer retorno, ao inves de `return`, exiba com `System.out.prinln`. O que importa na resposta lá não é o retorno, é você entender como foi feito e reproduzir conforme seu exercicio pede.

Comment: Consegui aqui @Articuno, valeu.

Comment: Caros fiz aqui e deu certo, mas teria como inverter o próprio vetor sem ter que criar outro?

Comment: SnSilva fiz um exemplo: https://repl.it/@inphinit/snsilvajava - funciona assim, clona o objeto (é necessário fazer isso por causa da referencia do objeto, então não tem como setar `vetor[i] = vetor[8]` sem afetar o array original causando conflito nos valores. O outro exemplo sem copiar/clonar array e usando métodos nativos é este: https://repl.it/@inphinit/snsilvajava - cc @Articuno

Comment: Dá pra fazer sem ter que criar um novo, a sua lógica da pergunta está certa, basta abstrair o tamanho do array, veja: https://ideone.com/bxYEt8 c/c @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @Articuno sensacional! :D

Comment: @Articuno isso era exatamente o que eu precisava, muito obrigado mesmo. Como faço para votar nessa solução como resolvida?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento valeu pela prestatividade, ficou bacana o exemplo no repl.it.